# Is there a CSS Snippet that would take out extra padding around the top/bottom of Home Page logo image? Big Cartel Sunscreen Theme

Tags: header, padding, bigcartel

I have been able to make several changes to the Advanced theme code on my Big Cartel website (Sunscreen Theme), however, there is one thing I can't figure out how to do.  I have attached a screenshot of the top of my Home Page where the header is showing the extra space above and below the logo image. [Website Header with Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9uiL.png) Is there a quick fix for taking out this extra space, like a snippet of CSS code I could add? Thanks in advance for your reply!

I have tried several CSS snippets I found in online searches where I could change the padding amount on top/bottom of the logo, however, they didn't work.  I have also scoured the Advance theme code page to find where I could make changes to the padding around the logo image, but couldn't find anything.